# MP3 with Pyaudio

Tags: python, mp3, playback, pyaudio

```
import pyaudio
import wave

chunk = 1024
wf = wave.open('yes.mp3', 'rb')
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(
    format = p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
    channels = wf.getnchannels(),
    rate = wf.getframerate(),
    output = True)
data = wf.readframes(chunk)

while data != '':
    stream.write(data)
    data = wf.readframes(chunk)

stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

No matter how I put this, while trying multiple methods I seem to keep getting the following error in terminal:

```
raise Error, 'file does not start with RIFF id'
```

I would use pyglet but media and all other modules aren't detected even though I'm able to import pyglet.

Any help?

Comment: Where is problem happening? When you open the mp3 file with `wave.open` or when you are tying to use the `wf` variable ??

Comment: No clue honestly, I was hoping I could play around with it to see what does what but so far every method I found on Google gives me this same error.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `wave` to attempt to open a file that is not `wav`.  Instead, you're attempting to open an `mp3` file. The `wave` module can only open `wav` files, so you need to convert the `mp3` to `wav`.  Here's how you can use pyglet to play an `mp3` file:

```
        import pyglet

        music = pyglet.resource.media('music.mp3')
        music.play()

        pyglet.app.run()
```

It would be much simpler than the method you're trying.  What errors are you getting with pyglet?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyglet2.py", line 3, in <module>
    music = pyglet.resource.media('/Dropbox/Grad_project/Tests/yes.mp3')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyglet/resource.py", line 592, in media
    raise ResourceNotFoundException(name)
pyglet.resource.ResourceNotFoundException: Resource "/Dropbox/Grad_project/Tests/yes.mp3" was not found on the path.  Ensure that the filename has the correct captialisation."

Yes the path is correct, and the spelling is correct as well (Just putting the MP3 and no path gives the same error as well.

Comment: Really? path is correct? You have a "Dropbox" folder in the root path of your filesystem? Try removing the initial "/" in the path..